# Using R survey package to rake with missing data

Tags: r, survey, survey-weights, poststratification

I have some survey data and would like to address non-reponse bias by raking on 3 demographic variables for which I have decent population estimates from the American Community Survey.

The problem I am running into is that a few of the surveys are missing responses on one or more of the demographic variables (for example one survey is missing the 'Annual Household Income' entry and I am trying to rake on 'Annual Household Income'), and so these entries are NAN in the data.frame.

So far when I try to rake with a call like

```
csr_raked = rake(design=csr_design, 
                 sample.margins=list(~Stratum+Annual_HHI), 
                 population.margins = list(HHI_marginals))
```

where I am simply trying to rake on a single variable, I get the following error message:

```
Error in postStratify.survey.design(design, strata[[i]], population.margins[[i]],  : 
Strata in sample absent from population. This Can't Happen
```

From reading the `anesrake` documentation it looks like the `anesrake` package can handle this type of issue, so I thought that the `survey` package would as well and I just don't know how to tell it to (I would prefer to perform all analysis using a single package if possible).

Comment: Can you point to where `anesrake` documentation says what it does in this setting?

Comment: I was not reading the documentation it turns out, but a description of the `anesrake` package by the author which can be found here: https://web.stanford.edu/group/iriss/cgi-bin/anesrake/resources/RakingDescription.pdf The relevant text is at the bottom of page 6 in the Missing Data section.

Comment: Thanks. That's a reasonable approach, and it would actually be easier to implement inside `rake` than inside `calibrate`, though it might be a pain for standard error estimation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what you want the `rake` function to do here: you have a `NaN` category in the sample and you don't have it in the population; what scaling do you *want* for the weights where the value is `NaN` to match the sample to the population?

If you're happy to have no change in the weights for `NaN` observations you can use the sum of the weights for those observations as the population total for the `NaN` stratum. Or if you want them scaled up in proportion to total non-response, you can take the sum of the weights, scale it up for total non-response, and use that as the population total for the `NaN` stratum. But `rake` isn't going to guess.

If any function in the package were to have a feature for guessing the desired rescaling with missing strata, it would be `calibrate`. It currently doesn't, but if you sent the package author a request, with documentation of what you think it should do (and ideally an example with, eg, `anesrake`) there's an excellent chance it would be in the next version.

Comment: To be honest I am not clear on what I would want the `rake` function to do in this situation.  I am new to surveys and survey analysis, and this is my first time grappling with this issue, so I was hoping that someone else had encountered this issue before me and had an idea of what to do in this situation.